# Netbeans git plugin shows all files deleted

Tags: git, netbeans, netbeans-7

I updated my Netbeans to 7.3.1, and opened the existing projects in my local git repo.

The Netbeans git plugin shows that all the files are deleted.

Anyone knows why and how to fix this?

The name of this plugin is called "Git", version 1.8.2.1.

I am more than happy to provide any additional information needed to figure out this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That error ocurrs when renaming a file by only changing the case and giving a commit.
The next time you open netbeans the file is marked as deleted.

Netbeans warms about this issue and suggest to use the command line in that case.

[image]

Comment: netbeans git is really messed up, I've lost some files because of this. Also the message not always shows up, for me that I renamed a folder it never did.

Answer (score 0):

HI I recently had this issue. I was doing some work on a different machine therefore I had to clone the directory. The problem was that whenever I did this git marked several files as deleted however there was no record of me doing this. Reverting the version or pulling a fresh one didn't solve it as they would be unmarked then marked again automatically. I noticed that the .gitignore file was missing from the directory so I created a new .gitignore file and put it in the project root and everything seemed to sort itself out. As far as I can tell its a bug within the Jgit which is the version that netbeans uses which is slightly different to the official git version.